# Convert Java Frequency Sort to Kotlin

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, kotlin, frequency

I need to sort `List<String>` by the number of occurrences in my list (DESC), and to remove repetitions from there. I wrote this working algorithm in java:

```
 private List<String> sortByFrequency(List<String> sequence) {
    return
            sequence.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but it doesn't work for **Kotlin**:
[kotlin code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4JZ0.png)

because I get the following exception:

```
    Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
    required:
    Collector<in String!, Any!, Long!>!
    found:
    Collector<String!, *, Long!>!
```

and can't figure out how to resolve it. maybe can you tell me?

Comment: If I leave out the explicit typing for the Collector, it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Kotlin figure out the types for you. Don't specify the type parameters unless you need to. Kotlin will try its best to find the correct types.

There is only one place that you need to specify the type parameters, and that is the `Map.Entry.comparingByValue` call.

This compiles:

```
fun sortByFrequency(sequence: List<String>): List<String?>? {
    return sequence.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy({ it }, Collectors.counting()))
        .entries.stream()
        .sorted(
            Map.Entry.comparingByValue<String, Long>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        )
        .map { it.key }
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

However, the code still feels very Java-ish. IMO, this is more idiomatic Kotlin:

```
fun sortByFrequency(sequence: List<String>): List<String> {
    val comparator = compareByDescending<Map.Entry<String, Int>> { it.value }
        .thenBy { it.key }
    return sequence.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().entries
        .sortedWith(comparator).map { it.key }
}
```

Notice the use of [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/grouping-by.html) and [`eachCount`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html).

Comment: hey! big thanks for your answer, but I got compilation error for `return sequence.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().entries` raw: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter U in 

fun <T : Any!, U : Comparable<U!>!> comparing
(
keyExtractor: ((T!) → U!)!
)
: Comparator<T!>!
Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: @WLDRMND You didn't seem to copy my answer exactly. Anyway, I just found a more concise, more kotliny version. Remember that you need to specify the type parameter for `compareByDescending` (and `comparing` if you're talking about the previous revision of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes that `*` and `Any` are not meaning the same thing. They are treated as distinct types, so the compilation fails. In fact `*` can mean `in Nothing` or `out Any?` in Kotlin, depending on the context.

More info on the topic:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections

In your case Kotlin should be able to infer the correct types for the collector for you, so can leave them out.

Comment: If you know Java, `Any` is equivalent to `Object` (except for nullability), a type that includes every possible object; while `*` is a wildcard equivalent to `?`, referring to some unknown type that might or might not include an arbitrary object.